# Can't use MySQL extract() function in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've run the following query:

```
    UPDATE main_table, reference_table
  SET main_table.calc_column = 
    (CASE WHEN main_table.incr = "6AM" 
          THEN reference_table.col1+reference_table.col2+...
          WHEN main_table.incr = "12AM" 
          THEN reference_table.col7+reference_table.col8+...
          WHEN main_table.incr = "6PM" 
          THEN reference_table.col13+reference_table.col14+...
          ELSE reference_table.col19+reference_table.col20+...)
  WHERE main_table.month = extract(month from reference_table.thedate)
    AND main_table.day = extract(day from reference_table.thedate)
```

I've used `extract()` function since my reference_table doesn't have month and day columns but has the date column named thedate. I've used the `extract()` function on the `reference_table` many times before successfully, so, I know that there's nothing wrong with my extract function syntax. However, in this instance, MySQL complains. It probably has to do with the fact that I've used in the `WHERE` clause.

I know that this issue could get fixed if I added the month and day columns to the `reference_table` to avoid using the `extract()` function. However, I'm very reluctant to do that and would like to avoid it. How can I make it work?`

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?  An EXTRACT works just fine within a WHERE clause for me.

Comment: What datatype is thedate column?

Comment: The error I get is the following:

Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax near ') where tb.month_number = extract(month from Electrical_Usage.thedate) and tb.th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the original question, the reason you are getting this error is that the `CASE` expression is missing its `END`.

Comment: Thanks to you I already fixed it. I really appreciate your help. Couldn't have done it without you.